# Why can't I move #1001 into r5 on arm?

Tags: assembly, arm, immediate-operand

I have an RPi4 and I'm trying to write some code in assembly to loop 1000 times. The code works fine when I set a lower number of loops, but when I try to set it 1001, `gcc` says:

```
loop.s: Assembler messages:
loop.s:15: Error: invalid constant (3e9) after fixup
```

Here's the code:

```
.data
ms3: .asciz "%d\n"
.text
.global main
.extern printf
main:
    push {ip, lr}
    mov r1, #0
    mov r5, #1001

loop1000:
    push {r1}
    ldr r0, =ms3
    bl printf
    pop {r1}
    add r1, #1
    cmp r1, r5
    bne loop1000
    pop {ip, pc}
```

Comment: Is this thumb code?  Note that not all constants can be represented exactly on ARM.  Use `ldr r5, =#1001` to have the assembler figure out a solution.

Comment: You should use `movw` instead. The old way `ldr` results in memory access which is not desirable.

Comment: More specifically, I think Thumb mode's widest available-everywhere move-immediate takes an 8-bit constant + a rotation, where the rotate count has to be a multiple of 2.  If you're assembling for a new-enough CPU, GAS will use `movw` for an `ldr reg, =constant` when it's encodeable.  I've heard that ARMasm will always use an actual `ldr` from PC-relative memory.

Comment: @PeterCordes If you're talking about Thumb instruction format 3 (move/compare/add/subtract immediate), then there's no rotation applied. It's just a plain 8-bit constant (zero-extended to 32 bits).

Comment: @Michael: Thanks.  The immediate format I was thinking of does exist but only in ARM mode: 8-bit immediate rotated by an even count:  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/Chdfgchf.html.  For mov and many other ALU instructions in ARM mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are thinking arm not thumb, thumb2 has a weird one that is more than rotation...

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE clearly a thumb not thumb2 question otherwise gnu would have used the thumb2 instruction.  ldr = will replace with the optimial instruction it doesnt always use ldr (with gnu, other assembly languages may vary).

Comment: you should keep your stack aligned to conform with the abi, so instead of pushing r1 by itself put another register in there anything between r2 and r7 are a valid choice.  also if conforming to the abi (this has main in it so that doesnt matter, but in general, dont use r5).  this code resembles other homework projects we have seen recently so I suspect you are all taking the same class or reading the same book or using the same simulator or something like that...

Comment: @old_timer No, I just checked that ARM GCC 9.2.1 generates a code with literal pool access.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE yep, that is what I said.  If this is armv7 or armv7m then you can use movw which ldr equals will generate as demonstrated below (no need to use movw and then have keep changing your code for different values, ldr equals is far easier).  If this something else (armv4 thru armv6, (current) armv8m) then you cannot use movw so a pc-relative load or three instructions.  (Im using gcc 9.3.0, BTW, but thats not relevant)  so ldr equals is easiest for that situation.

Comment: Unless you have a strong desire to control where the relative load comes from and using gnu then the ldr equals is the best solution as it generates the smallest instruction (mov, movw, mvn, ldr, etc).  If not using gnu assembler then the best solution is based on the assembly language for your assembler.

Comment: Note this is assembly language not C so you would use gnu assembler not gcc, that is yet another assembly language, but I can easily edit my question...

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Even though I had already shown this, I edited my answer to demonstrate why movw doesnt work. Should be easy to reproduce with the last few versions of binutils and/or gcc at least, probably going back to the addition of thumb2 extensions for the cortex-m3 (and/or armv7-ar).  You can specify the cpu on the command line instead of in the code you will get the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assembly languages are defined by the tool not the target, so solutions and exact syntax for instructions varies.  You mentioned gcc which implies gnu assembler although gcc being fed assembly language is yet another gnu arm assembly language

With gnu assembler the ldr = pseudo instruction will attempt to use the optimal instruction if it can otherwise it will do a pc-relative load.  If you want full control then only use the ldr = thing for labels (clearly its original intent)

```
.cpu arm7tdmi
ldr r5,=1001
ldr r5,=0x00990000
ldr r5,=0x00990099
ldr r5,=0x90000009


.thumb
.cpu cortex-m0
ldr r5,=1001

.cpu cortex-m3
ldr r5,=1001
movw r5,#1001
ldr r5,=0x00990099
.align

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e59f5018    ldr r5, [pc, #24]   ; 20 <.text+0x20>
   4:   e3a05899    mov r5, #10027008   ; 0x990000
   8:   e59f5014    ldr r5, [pc, #20]   ; 24 <.text+0x24>
   c:   e3a05299    mov r5, #-1879048183    ; 0x90000009
  10:   4d03        ldr r5, [pc, #12]   ; (20 <.text+0x20>)
  12:   f240 35e9   movw    r5, #1001   ; 0x3e9
  16:   f240 35e9   movw    r5, #1001   ; 0x3e9
  1a:   f04f 1599   mov.w   r5, #10027161   ; 0x990099
  1e:   bf00        nop
  20:   000003e9    andeq   r0, r0, r9, ror #7
  24:   00990099    umullseq    r0, r9, r9, r0
```

starting in the middle with your question.

```
  10:   4d03        ldr r5, [pc, #12]   ; (20 <.text+0x20>)
```

1001 (0x3e9) does not fit within the 8 bit immediate,no rotation, of the mov immediate thumb instruction.  so using ldr = the assembler created a pc-relative load, which has pros and cons.

There is a thumb2 extension only available on some processors that does support larger immediates

```
  12:   f240 35e9   movw    r5, #1001   ; 0x3e9
```

It even can do weird things like this.

```
  1a:   f04f 1599   mov.w   r5, #10027161   ; 0x990099
```

both the ldr =  and directly using movw resulted in the same instruction (as expected).

```
  12:   f240 35e9   movw    r5, #1001   ; 0x3e9
  16:   f240 35e9   movw    r5, #1001   ; 0x3e9
```

There was some confusion in the comments (everyone needs to go read the documentation not just the OP)

```
   0:   e59f5018    ldr r5, [pc, #24]   ; 20 <.text+0x20>
   4:   e3a05899    mov r5, #10027008   ; 0x990000
   8:   e59f5014    ldr r5, [pc, #20]   ; 24 <.text+0x24>
   c:   e3a05299    mov r5, #-1879048183    ; 0x90000009
```

arm mode cannot do the 0x00990099 thing, but it can do 8 non-zero bits rotated on an even boundary 0x00990000 and 0x90000009, but not 0x000001FE, 0x102, and so on.

arm uses 32 bit instructions and like mips and others is limited in how many bits of immediate are possible while leaving room for the opcode for lack of a better term.  thumb is 16 bit so much less room is available for an immediate.  thumb2 extensions add additional instructions that take 2x16 bits but couldn't use arm encoding in general but for some reason didn't use the same immediate scheme that you see in arm instructions, so you have this reflect and shift thing rather than just a shift thing.

All of this is in the arm documentation which you should have next to you when writing/learning assembly language.

Assembly language is defined by the tool (the assembler) not the target, so gnu assembler and kiel and ARMasm and others are expected to have different assembly languages (mostly in the non-instruction area) and they do.  Same for any other target (x86, mips, etc) this is a general rule there aren't standardized assembly languages usually, certainly not for the mainline instruction sets.

Saying that the ldr rx,=label/address trick has with gnu assembler resulted in the optimal instruction, but it pseudo code not a real instruction and as such it is not expected to be supported at all on some assemblers and some that support it may literally implement a pc relative load and not optimize (within the realm of possibilities that one might have a command line option to enable/disable the optimization).

You built for thumb and for thumb you are limited to an unshifted 8 bit immediate.  If your cpu happens to support thumb2 as well then you can tell the assembler that command line or in the code and it will generate the optimized instruction and/or you can specify the instruction directly.  If thumb2 is not supported then you can either directly craft a pc relative load

```
mov r5,hello
...
hello: .word 1001
```

or use the ldr equals thing, or use multiple instructions 3 shifted left 8 orred with 0xE9, that kind of thing.

### Edit

Just for Jake...

```
.thumb

.cpu cortex-m0
ldr r5,=1001

.cpu cortex-m3
ldr r5,=1001

.align

arm-none-eabi-as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.34
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `arm-none-eabi'.

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4d01        ldr r5, [pc, #4]    ; (8 <.text+0x8>)
   2:   f240 35e9   movw    r5, #1001   ; 0x3e9
   6:   bf00        nop
   8:   000003e9    andeq   r0, r0, r9, ror #7
```

for armv6m (and armv4t, armv5t, armv6, current armv8ms) you cannot use movw, which is what was implied by the OPs error message.

For armv7, armv7m you can and the ldr instruction generates that, instead of having to keep changing your code based on what immediates you choose, if you use gnu assembler then ldr equals is the best way to go.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4d01        ldr r5, [pc, #4]    ; (8 <.text+0x8>)
   2:   f240 35e9   movw    r5, #1001   ; 0x3e9
   6:   bf00        nop
   8:   000003e9    andeq   r0, r0, r9, ror #7
```

Now while feeding assembly language through gcc is yet another assembly language it still as expected generates the ideal instruction when ldr equals is used.  Where you can use movw it does, where you cannot it does not, but let's try this.

```
.thumb

.cpu cortex-m0
ldr r5,=1001

.cpu cortex-m3
movw r5,#1001

.align
```

No complaints. Same results.

Trying your suggestion:

```
.thumb

.cpu cortex-m0
movw r5,#1001

.cpu cortex-m3
movw r5,#1001

.align

arm-none-eabi-gcc so.s -c -o so.o
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:6: Error: selected processor does not support `movw r5,#1001' in Thumb mode
```

and now you have to go re-write your code.  movw is not a good solution.

### Edit 2 (for the OP)

bottom line, short answer... The reason why you got that message is that you cannot generate a thumb mov immediate instruction with that immediate value because you will see in the arm documentation you don't have that many bits.  If when you said rapi 4 you meant raspberry pi 4 that is an armv8 which supports aarch32 (armv7-a) which supports thumb2 extensions (which post armv6-m includes movw)

```
.thumb
ldr r5,=1001
.align
```

Use ldr equals to discover the optimal instruction

```
arm-none-eabi-as -march=armv7a so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f240 35e9   movw    r5, #1001   ; 0x3e9
```

and then use that directly if you wish

```
.thumb
ldr r5,=1001
movw r5,#1001
.align

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f240 35e9   movw    r5, #1001   ; 0x3e9
   4:   f240 35e9   movw    r5, #1001   ; 0x3e9
```

If this is indeed a raspberry pi 4 then you need the armv7-ar architectural reference manual to cover the aarch32 stuff and the armv8 (not 8m) architectural reference manual to cover the aarch64 stuff.  And a different gnu toolchain as it is a completely different instruction set (aarch64-whatever-whatever vs arm-whatever-whatever).  And there are no thumb instructions in aarch64 (yet).

Comment: note the ldr equals thing if it needs to implement a pc relative load needs a pool nearby which sometimes the tool cant find and .pool or the newer directive may need to be used or you may need an unconditional branch over a pool depending on your code.   rare, but happens.  Likewise if you explicitly place a value for a pc relative load it has to be within the reach of that addressing mode.

Comment: For effort alone it would be worth it -- but there are some nuggets here (the arm guide open ... is a top recommendation). It's almost easier for someone to learn arm assembly from scratch than it is to come from an x86 background into the world of load-store and the differing arm models. A good tutorial always helps it sink in [Azeria - Memory Instructions: Load and Store](https://azeria-labs.com/memory-instructions-load-and-store-part-4/) is worth a shout-out there.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin nice page, but it is talking about full sized arm instructions the issue here was thumb.  good start would be good with disassemblies showing the instruction and why and then add thumb and thumb2  to round it out and maybe aarch64.  Saved that link in m bookmarks though, I dont need it clearly but good to send to others or link here at SO instead of writing all that stuff out (really doesnt take but one to a few fives of minutes to write all of the above).

Comment: if desired I can easily rip up this answer and just put the short version at the end...

Comment: The OP explicitly stated `rpi 4`. I don't know why you mention `cortex-m`. And if I wanted portability, assembly is the last in my list. In other words, only the best is good enough, if I write something in assembly. No, I wouldn't resort to unnecessary literal pool access in my codes.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE  I completely rewrote the answer based on that angle but this one was selected, oh well.  ldr equals uses the optimized solution so it will only use the literal pool as a last resort which you would have to do manually in that same case (or use multiple instructions) at least for the last so many major revs of gcc/binutils (I tested back to gcc5 and its partner gas, produces the movw as desired).  You could have just answered it yourself.  cortex-m is the easiest way to explain the different thumb instruction sets.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE assembly language is by definition not portable so that doesnt make sense.  it takes a lot more effort every time you change a constant to dabble around with different instructions rather than just asking the assembler to choose the optimized one.  Yes, some of us know the rules and can pick the right instruction but most dont so to avoid SO questions like this and waiting hours for answers to roll in, can use a tool like this one to just give you the answer, then if you choose switch to that instruction (on this or some other assembler) for that constant.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE please post your answer so that the OP can switch and I can delete this one.